# How to fix error 'another rcp application is running in this sandbox'

Tags: rtc

When I attempt to run an 'scm load' I receive this error :

> another rcp application is running in this sandbox file locked at file
>   c:\workspaces\myworkspace

How can this error be fixed ?

I've successfully used the scm load command before so maybe I need to perform some 'tidying up' after I load a workspace as this just occurs when I change workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/94069/cannot-execute-scm-from-ant-build-script-while-rtc-is-running-message-is-another-rcp-application-is-running-in-this-sandbox-exit-code-27) sums it up:

> Two potential solutions:
>
> 1. Run `lscm.bat` instead of "`scm.exe`" to do the checkin
>      `lscm` will contact your RTC eclipse client to perform the checkin
> 2. Use a separate sandbox and repository workspace
>      Use `scm.exe` to load a repository workspace into a separate sandbox (e.g. c:\Workspaces\sandbox1)
>
>    - Make changes to the files in that sandbox
>    - Use `scm.exe` to check in those changes and deliver them

Comment: In general: scm on build (https://jazz.net/library/article/195) is interesting, but can lead to your error message when the same local workspace is used.

Comment: could you elaborate on a 'separate sandbox' ? Where is this defiined ?

Comment: by separate sandbox I think you mean a new local dir, it works now

Comment: @user470184 yes, separate dir. Sorry, I didn't see your comment right away.